# How to cancel Observable if user left component?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have Observable request to server:

```
let request = of(1).pipe(delay(6000));
```

Then I activate loader passing observer inside and subscribe:

```
   this.spinnerService.activate(request);
   this.$sub = request.subscribe((data) => {});
```

In `ngOnDestroy` I kill all Observables:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$sub.unsubscribe();
    this.spinnerService.disactivate();
  }
```

So problem is how to cancel observer `request` inside service?

Service is:

```
export class SpinnerService {
  private preloaderState$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private stop$ = new Subject();

  public activate(
    obs: Observable<any>[],
    startAfterMilliseconds: number = 1000,
    finishAfterMilliseconds: number = 0
  ) {
    forkJoin(obs).subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log("Finish loader...");
        this.disactivate();
      },
      (error) => console.log("ERROR: " + error)
    );

    of(true)
      .pipe(delay(startAfterMilliseconds), takeUntil(this.stop$))
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log("Run loader...");
          this.preloaderState$.next(true);
        },
        (error) => console.log("ERROR:" + error)
      );
  }

  public disactivate() {
    this.preloaderState$.next(false);
    this.stop$.next();
    this.stop$.complete();
    console.log("Disactivate all..");
  }

  public preloader(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.preloaderState$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Why when I stop everything:

```
this.$sub.unsubscribe();
this.spinnerService.disactivate();
```

forkJoin is still awaiting response from server. How to cancel `forkJoin(obs)`?

Comment: Since services will not be using the actual data, I would just return the observable from the service method, subscribe in my component where I am expecting the data and unsubscribe in the same component's ngOnDestroy() method.

Comment: See my updated service, problem is that I can not cancel forkJoin despite external request was canceklled

Comment: I have tried:  `this.stopFork = forkJoin(obs).subscribe()` Then ` this.stopFork.unsubscribe()` in  `public disactivate() {}`

Comment: You can try using takeUntill operatror `forkJoin(obs)
.takeUntil(this.stop$)
.subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log("Finish loader...");
        this.disactivate();
      },
      (error) => console.log("ERROR: " + error)
    );
`

Comment: Could you explain me how to collect all observables from current page(outcoming requests) and then await  1 seconds then if no fork finished, run another proccess?